# jQuery change value when toggleClass is active

Tags: jquery

Need help about this scenario. I have a dropdown menu with a "+" button. I wanted to make it "-" when it drops down the menu. When it turns back, it will go back to "+". Flexible.

This is what i meant:

[image]

This is my jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.dropdown-menu').not($(this).next('.dropdown-menu')).fadeOut()
        $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').fadeToggle().toggleClass('isOpen');
        $(".dropdown-toggle").val("-");
    });
});
</script>
```

here's my html:

```
<button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Test</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Test</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Test</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Test</a></li>    
   <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Test</a></li>        
</ul>
```

Thank you so much whoever helps me enlighten with jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the innerHTML property of the domElement instead of value.

```
document.querySelector(".dropdown-toggle").innerHTML = "-";
```

jQuery equivalent is html() function.

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").html("-");
```

If you will:

```
 console.dir(document.querySelector(".dropdown-toggle"))
```

And expand it, you will see that value property is an empty string and the innerHTML is "+"

Comment: Aleksei - got it. how can I make it flexible? when its not open. currently, they are all in "-" when I click specific dropdown.

Comment: @KobeBryan expalin some more, what do you mean flexible? As if they all turn into "-" when you click one of them?

Comment: @alekei - what i mean is when I close the dropdown menu, the sign is still "-". It should go back to "+" when the dropdown is closed.

Comment: @KobeBryan check for some condition to determine wheter you need it to change to "+" or "-" ... If ($(event.target).hasClass('isOpen')) { //set to "-" }

Comment: got it. if else statement was the solution. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Set some basic **html elements**:

```
<button id='dog_button'>Dogs</button>
<div id='hold'></div>
```

Add your **styling**:

```
body {
  font-family: arial; 
}

button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none; 
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: gold; 
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show {
  width: 180px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #dedede;
  padding: 10px;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Use **jQuery** to toggle categories and options as needed:

```
categories_and_ops = {
    'Dog Beds' : ['Soft Dog Beds','Matress Dog Beds','Plastic Dog Beds','3 Peaks','Dog Blankets','Heating Dog Beds', 'Specific Dog Beds', 'Luxury Dog Beds'],
    'Dog Coats' : ['...','...','...','...','...','...', '...', '...']
}

$('#dog_button').click(function() {
$.each(categories_and_ops, function(cat, op) {
div_id = 'div_' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
$('#hold').append("<div class='show' id=" + div_id + "></div><br>")
$('#' + div_id).append("<span style='color:orange; font-weight: bold'>" + cat + "</span><div class='square'>-</div><br>" + '<br>') 
op.forEach(function(op_elem) { $('#' + div_id).append('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + "<span class='ops'>" + op_elem + "</span>" + '<br><br>') })
})
})

$(document).on('click', '.square', function() {
if($(this).html() == '-') {
$(this).parent().children('.ops').toggle();
$(this).html('+');
} else {
$(this).parent().children('.ops').toggle();
$(this).html('-');
}
})
```

**Result**:

[image]